# XAMPP PHP ports? file_get_contents_curl quits working

Tags: php, curl, xampp, port

I have been programming a search engine just for the heck of it, but now that I am done with my indexers (about 50ish) I want to run at least 20 of them, but every time I use more than 10 it seems like file_gets_contents_curl

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}
```

quits working. I hope you know what I am talking about, because I don't know a lot of that stuff

Can I change the php.ini anywhere to avoid this error?

Thanks for helping

edit
Error Log

```
[Sat Apr 13 00:27:09.571840 2013] [core:warn] [pid 720:tid 336] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?

[Sat Apr 13 00:27:09.644889 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 720:tid 336] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]

[Sat Apr 13 00:27:09.690919 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 720:tid 336] AH00455: Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7 configured -- resuming normal operations

[Sat Apr 13 00:27:09.690919 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 720:tid 336] AH00456: Server built: Aug 18 2012 12:41:37

[Sat Apr 13 00:27:09.690919 2013] [core:notice] [pid 720:tid 336] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'

[Sat Apr 13 00:27:09.691920 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 720:tid 336] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6876

[Sat Apr 13 00:27:10.196255 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 6876:tid 360] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]

[Sat Apr 13 00:27:10.241286 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6876:tid 360] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'quits working'? Errors? Something in your log files?

Comment: `$content = file_get_contents_curl($url) or die('&quot;' . $url . '&quot; couldn't load');`   this is just where I noticed that it stopped